# What is the * in tcp://*?

Tags: tcp, endpoint

For example in code like this:

`java
final String socketEndpoint =  "tcp://*:" + port;`

Is the * a stand-in for localhost (or 128.0.0.1, or 128.0.0.0) or something?

Comment: I would proffer it's a wildcard binding to any hostname combination on the host machine.

Comment: I would ask what's the "tcp" part. This URL isn't something Java recognizes. You would have to look at the code that uses this string.